# sql - Delete/omit rn column within query result, using ROW_NUMBER function

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have several unique IDs, these unique ID's have repeating data based on

> timestamp

.

I get the latest data by `timestamp` for each unique ID in the following way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT uniqueID, timestamp
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY uniqueID ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn 
      FROM table_name
     ) a 
WHERE rn = 1
```

This works, but the query also returns a rn column. So my result set looks like this:

```
uniqueID timestamp rn
1        15:00     1
2        15:00     1
```

How can i omit the column rn from the query-reults? To make it look like this:

```
uniqueID timestamp
1        15:00
2        15:00
```

Ref: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/

Comment: Specify the columns instead of `select *`

Comment: Simply specify the columns to select.

Comment: Why do you link to a postgres tutorial when your question is tagged with sql-server?

Comment: I want to use the result of this query with an INSERT INTO statement, to store the result once a day in a Historical table that is equal to the origin table. So specifying the columns gives an error:  The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns

Comment: * these unique ID's have repeating data based on timestamp.* so much for unique....

Comment: Specify columns of both tables to avoid the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your query like following. You don't need to put `*`, just mention the column you need.

```
SELECT a.uniqueid , 
       a.timestamp 
FROM   ( 
        SELECT   uniqueid, 
                    timestamp, row_number() OVER(partition BY uniqueid ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
        FROM     table_name) a 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Works like a charm, i only specified in the Insert into statement :) So above answers are also correct.

Comment: Great, please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your query.

Comment: I tried i think, maybe my reputation is not high enough...No it was not the problem: Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of columns, you might find it simpler to do:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_name a 
WHERE a.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(a2.timestamp) FROM table_name a2 WHERE a2.uniqueid = a.uniqueid);
```

In addition, this probably has slightly better performance if you have an index on `(uniqueid, timestamp)`.

Ironically, Postgres has a simpler solution (and you are referring to a Postgres tutorial):

```
select distinct on (uniqueid) a.*
from table_name a
order by uniqueid, timestamp desc;
```